# Hash states without "popstate"

Tags: javascript, ajax, hash, hashtag, popstate

I'm trying to load different content with JavaScript on a page, depending on its hash tag. However, it should also work in older browsers which do not support the [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) method.

The problem is, that when looking at `window.location.hash` after I click on a link (e.g. `#newhashtag`) on the current page (e.g. `example.com/#currenthashtag`), on `document.ready` it still shows me the old hash tag. Only after clicking on a second link, the previous hash tag from the first link shows up in `window.location.hash`.

**So, what is the easiest way to handle different hash states of a website without using popstate?**

Comment: Have you looked for popstate polyfills?

Comment: Not yet. Also, I found out that popstate is slightly delayed in respect to document.ready - which would also delay the page speed when loading new content which is not desired.